# Append a text in the end of the url php

Tags: php

i need to add a text in the end of the url while user click on a button.

for example :
www.example.com/people/xyz
 when the user click the button, it should go to 
www.example.com/people/xyz/edit

i did a search, & built code, but it didn't work, here it's :

```
$editlink = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo '<a href ="<?php $editlink;?>/edit" class="btn btn-info" role="button">EDIT</a>'
```

Please Help me to solve it

Comment: you're getting a parse error but you're not letting it show you

Comment: You're already coding in php, why open the php brackets, and not just parse it in? `<a href=" '.$editlink.'/edit" class="btn btn-info" role="button">EDIT</a>`. You should probably also turn `error_reporting()` on by adding this code at the top of your code: `error_reporting(-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your code as follows:

```
<?php
$editlink = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<a href ="<?php echo $editlink;?>/edit" class="btn btn-info" role="button">EDIT</a>
```